# "Cannot autowire service" exception when trying to clear Symfony 4 application cache

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a project under Symfony 4 and when i try to do an composer update to my project i got this error

```
     Executing script cache:clear 
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1[KO]
!!
!!  In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:
!!  

!!    Cannot autowire service "App\Repository\ActeRepository": argument "$registry" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Br  
!!    idge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface" but no such service exists. Try changing the type-hint to "Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry" instea  
!!    d.

!!  

!!
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
 [KO]
<?php
```

and the ActeRepository is the follow

```
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Acte;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

/**
 * @method Acte|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Acte|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Acte[]    findAll()
 * @method Acte[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class ActeRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Acte::class);
    }

    // /**
    //  * @return Acte[] Returns an array of Acte objects
    //  */
    /*
    public function findByExampleField($value)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->orderBy('a.id', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
    */

    /*
    public function findOneBySomeField($value): ?Acte
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.exampleField = :val')
            ->setParameter('val', $value)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }
    */
}
```

I don't now where is the problem and the project can not update i also try to delete the var and vendor file and clear the cache of composer and Symfony but the same problem appear i don't now why i found multiple proposed solution but they not work ??

Comment: Consider the following: RegistryInterface has been deprecated in DoctrineBridge (v4.4) and has been replaced with Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry in MakerBundle 1.13

Comment: This has nothing to do with Composer. You misconfigured dependency injection settings of your app: exclude Doctrine repositories from the autowiring.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor should look like this:

```
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
{
    parent::__construct($registry, Acte::class);
}
```

Add use statement:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
```

Extend class with:

```
extends ServiceEntityRepository
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue just remove your constructor in `ActeRepository.php`, it's not needed.

It's an autowire issue, so you have to init the field in your repository if you want to keep it here.

If it doesn't work, try to change the param type in your constructor :

```php
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class ActeRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Acte::class);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i try the both of solution but the same problem appear

Comment: If it didn't worked with `ManagerRegistry $registry` but worked with `\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry $registry`, it's just because you forgot the `use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;`...

Answer (score -1):

i just replace in all Repository file
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry) => public function __construct(\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry $registry)
thinks